# Difference between finish() and this.finish() in android

Tags: java, android

Providing `finish()` and `this.finish()` in `onPause()` or `onStop()` method is same?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Please become familiar with meaning of `this.` -> it's value is the reference to the current object. For example, if you have a class named `Foo`, and it has method named `method()`, then `this` in it would be a reference to a instance of the `Foo` (that is: a `Foo` object). Usually you do not need to use `this`.

Answer (score 2):

`this` in any context refers to the containing class. So, if you are using the method inside an `Activity`, then `this.finish()` is same as `finish().` However, if you are using `this` in a different class type, you may not have `this.finish()`

Answer (score 2):

Even though the question is 3 years old.I prefer to torch some light over the present and future researchers.

`this` is just an object reference.You don't have to use `this` every time ,other than you need to get a reference of parent class from a child class instance.

Let's consider an example when using `Thread` class.

```
public class A
{
   public A()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable()
         {
             public void start()
             {
                  B child=new B(A.this);//In this scenario,'A.this' refers to the parent class 'A' in which the 'Thread' class instantiated.If you simply pass 'this' ,then it would refer to the 'Thread' class as this statement executed in the current scope.
             }
         }).start();
    }
}
public class B
{
A parent;
    public B(A parent)
    {
        this.parent=parent;//'this' refers to the class B ,so that it can access the global variable 'parent' ,then assigns it with the local variable 'parent' passed through the constructor.
    }
}
```

Like listed above ,there are different usages of `this` keyword.Its better to refer the oracle's documentation over here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 0):

`finish()` and `this.finish()` is the same.

For the other part of the question, please [read about the Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your case It's the same. It's sometimes important to use this->... if you have an member and an method parameter with the same name like in the following example:

```
    class foo{

    int number;

    void setNumber(int number);

    }
```

so you can write in your method

```
    void foo::setNumber(int number)
    {
    this->number = number; 
    }
```

And so It's clear which element you have used. But be careful don't use the same names it's not really nice.

Comment: The OP asked about Java, not about C++.

Comment: oh, sorry - you are right. I've written my example in c++ - sorry